# Countries Field for Freeform

Tags: custom-field, freeform

The Freeform docs say there is a predefined option for Countries, but I do not see it anywhere in the Field types or existing fields. How does one access this? Using the latest version of both Craft and Freeform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer: after you create a "select field", name it whatever you want - in this case country - and then add it to a form. Once you have done that, select that field within the form and edit in the properties column. Under Option Editor > Source, select "Predefined Options", then under > Target, select the option set you want, e.g. Countries, States, etc.

Seems to me that this should be part of the field creation process, rather than doing it in the form, but once you understand how to do it, it works great.